# AlertDialog in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have some difficulties getting `AlertDialog` working in fragments. I have six buttons and when each button is clicked `AlertDialog` box should display its content. even though the prg is running without any error and tat fragment page is opening with the buttons if i click on a button dialogbox is not opening can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Here is my fragment activity code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Fragment3 extends  DialogFragment implements OnClickListener  {

    private static final int ALERT_DIALOG1 = 1;
  private static final int ALERT_DIALOG2 = 2;
  private static final int ALERT_DIALOG3 = 3;
  private static final int ALERT_DIALOG4 = 4;
  private static final int ALERT_DIALOG5 = 5;



  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment2);
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3layout, container, false);

      Button alert1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
      alert1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
          showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG1);
      }
  });



 default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;

}
```

Here is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pacificstereoapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a.Fragment1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment1" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: dialog.show() line is missing

Comment: you must have added your alert specific code only no need of adding a full code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating dialog, but not really showing it. Call `dialog.show()`.

Comment: I added the dialog.show() as below 

public void showDialog(int alertDialog1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog(alertDialog1);
 dialog.setOwnerActivity(this.getActivity());
 dialog.show();
 }

but getting this error

windowmanager$badtokenexception
in logcat

Comment: Instead of `builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());`, use `builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());`