# create dialog box android

Tags: android, dialog

I'm new at coding Android applications and I want to know how to create a dialog box. I've looked at the page on [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) but I'm not sure.

Do I have to create an Activity or a Class with the name `DialogFragment` as in this example?

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment { ... }
```

Because I haven't created any `DialogFragment` so Eclipse doesn't know it. Maybe I have to introduce some code in an other file like an .xml or a .java?

The point is to have a Dialog like this:

```
public class QuestionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_question)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // Answering the question by yes or no or a date picker
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you any knowledge about fragments?

Comment: No, don't know what it is... Cause I couldn't find something like "create an XML file, i cannot create a fragment right ?
I'm gonna read on android developpers if it's easier for you to explain me if I know something about it

Comment: Assuming that you know already how to use activities, instead of using DialogFragment use AlertDialog

Comment: possible duplicate of [AlertDialog in fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889174/alertdialog-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does know it, but you have to point it out, at the top of the file where you use `DialogFragment`:

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
// OR
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; // Depending on the target version
```

Comment: Like this one : Multiple markers at this line
 - Class requires API level 11 (current min is 8): 
  android.app.DialogFragment

Comment: Yes, that's the versioning I was talking about... Fragments are quite recent, they were only introduced in API level 11. To used them before, you must use the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Comment: Ok. I'll read this link. Will I be able to see the Dialogbox on the graphical layout or do I have to use the emulator ? Cause it takes 15 minutes to open it and it always crashes...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to see it in the graphical layout... But the emulator should not crash, just you app (if there is reason for that). o_O

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks anyway, you helped me a lot even if now I have " R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
" error ...